# How can I compare the file extension to what typed in the textbox without the dot first?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm searching in files. And depending on the extension I type in textBox2 that the files types I want to search in. For example if I typed in the textBox2 .txt it will search all text files. But I don't want to type .cs or .txt I want to type only cs or only txt

```
string restrictedFile = "";
        List<string> restrictedFiles = new List<string>();
        int numberofrestrictedFiles = 0;
        int numberoffiles = 0;
        IEnumerable<string> SearchAccessibleFilesNoDistinct(string root, List<string> files,BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            _busy.WaitOne();
            if (files == null)
                files = new List<string>();
            if (Directory.Exists(root))
            {
                foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(root))
                {
                    if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        return files;
                    }
                    restrictedFile = file;
                    string ext = Path.GetExtension(file);
                    if (!files.Contains(file) && ext == textBox2.Text)
                    {
                        files.Add(file);
                    }
                    numberoffiles++;
                    label24.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        label24.Text = numberoffiles.ToString();
                        label24.Visible = true;
                    });
                }
                foreach (var subDir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root))
                {
                    if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        return files;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        SearchAccessibleFilesNoDistinct(subDir, files,worker, e);
                    }
                    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                    {
                        restrictedFiles.Add(restrictedFile);
                        numberofrestrictedFiles++;
                        label11.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                        {
                            label11.Text = numberofrestrictedFiles.ToString();
                            label11.Visible = true;
                        });
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            return files;
        }
```

At this part I'm getting the file extension and check if in the textBox2 it's the same. But since the file extension is .txt or .cs or .gif I have to type in the textBox2 also with '.' and instead I want to be able to type only cs gif txt....

Another sub question, How can I make that it will search in all any of files extension ? For example if I type in the textBox2 he string ALL or maybe *.* so it will search all the extensions.

Comment: If you want to type just `txt` or `cs` in `textbox2` then you should declare a string variable `var fileType = "." + textBox2.Text;` and use that variable as `if (!files.Contains(file) && ext == fileType)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EnumerateFiles has a [prototype that accepts a search filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_EnumerateFiles_System_String_System_String_). It is more efficient to let the operating system filter the files than to filter them in code yourself.

To get files with a particular extension, search like this:

```
EnumerateFiles(root, "*." + extension);
```

To get all files, use this:

```
EnumerateFiles(root, "*.*");
```

To cover both cases, you could use:

```
var extension = Textbox2.Text;
if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(extension)) extension = "*.*";
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(root, extension)
{
    //etc....
```

Answer (score 0):

Path.GetExtension returns the extension with the . (.docx), so you can change your if criteria to add this automatically:

```
if (!files.Contains(file) && ext == "." + textBox2.Text)
```